# Mercurial + IIS push error 10054

Tags: iis, mercurial, tortoisehg

Getting this error when trying to push to our mercurial repository:

**An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I don't believe related to the size of the push as it's occurring on a push that's about 140kb.  Everything was working fine about a week ago.

Any ideas?

Here's the log:

```
    4 changesets found
    list of changesets:
    8b53bd8082b543c713c473486e0923837e186551
    6be81c93e5c78c575670bb5f0ad11181bd2728bf
    0d7073fa9250320a576f5ec31fa6951ccb68691c
    04e70027f6435925d43778eecf9b4e0e07da12ee
    bundling: 1/4 changesets (25.00%)
    bundling: 2/4 changesets (50.00%)
    bundling: 3/4 changesets (75.00%)
    bundling: 4/4 changesets (100.00%)
    bundling: 1/4 manifests (25.00%)
    bundling: 2/4 manifests (50.00%)
    bundling: 3/4 manifests (75.00%)
    bundling: 4/4 manifests (100.00%)
    bundling: library/images/fratto.jpg 1/2 files (50.00%)
    bundling: library/images/raghu.jpg 2/2 files (100.00%)
    sending unbundle command
    sending 74493 bytes
    sending: 64/144 kb (44.44%)
    www.example.com certificate successfully verified
    sending: 128/144 kb (88.89%)
    abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Server is Windows 2008 R2 64 bit, Running Mercurial v 2.9.2 with python 2.7.6 and tortoisehg 2.11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was custom error pages in IIS! These were inherited custom error pages for our ColdFusion website.  I took them all off and now it's working like a charm.